# Is there a way to smooth out flat edges without making it lose its shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh

For the most part i want a flat and solid body but there are parts where it comes across as low poly instead, I want to know if there is a way to fix this problem without subdivision or manually editing it in edit mode [image]

Comment: You can right click in *Object* mode and *Shade Smooth*, then in the *Object Data panel > Normals* > enable *Auto Smooth* and find the good angle. If you only want some faces to be smoothed and not some others, go in *Edit* mode, select the faces, press Ctrl F > *Shade Smooth*

Answer (score 3):

Like moonboots said, you can right-click in *object mode* to shade smooth. If you want to manually make edges look sharp, while others remain flat, turn *Auto Smooth* up to the maximum value, go into *Edit Mode*, select the edge selection mode, select the edges you want to be seen as sharp, then, at the top of the vewport, click  *Edge>Mark Sharp*